# Many to Many Mapping Using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, mapping, data-annotations

```
[Table("UserMaster")]
public class UserMaster  
{
    public UserMaster()
    {
        this.Roles = new List<Role>();
    }

    [Key]    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
 } 



[Table("Role")]
public class Role 
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new List<UserMaster>();
    }
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserMaster> Users { get; set; }

}
```

I map these tables using EntityTypeConfiguration and it triggers OnModelCreate

```
this.HasMany(a => a.Roles).WithMany(b => b.Users).Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            m.ToTable("UsersInRoles");
        });
```

I wonder If there Is a way to map them in the class Role or UserMaster. We can use

```
[ForeignKey()]
[Key]
[Table()]
```

Could we do the mapping thing also?

Comment: I am still confused what you want to do? Fluent API or Data Annotation? I myself would prefer using Fluent API since I don't need to pollute my models by attributes.

Comment: I am alread doing it using Fluent Api the question is i want to do the mapping usinh Data Annotation

Comment: @CuongLe How is adding meaningful information about model properties "polluting"?  It's easier to understand than following the Fluent API code.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to customize entity framework code first for many to many relationship using data annotation, you must add junction class as the following :

```
[Table("UsersInRoles")]
public class UsersInRoles
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("UserMaster")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public UserMaster UserMaster { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

and then related classes must be changed to :

```
[Table("UserMaster")]
public class UserMaster  
{
    public UserMaster()
    {
        this.Roles = new List<Role>();
    }

    [Key]    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UsersInRoles> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
 } 



[Table("Role")]
public class Role 
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new List<UserMaster>();
    }
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<UsersInRoles> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
}
```

and also see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d7a4803-53c6-44be-823d-dce6e85bb497/ef-41-customize-codefirst-manytomany-table-using-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Since I got here from top google results, and I needed to find solution for **EF Core**, @Mohsen solution did not work for me.
However, what I found after some digging is that you can use `PrimaryKey` attribute in `EF7`. The `[PrimaryKey]` attribute was introduced in `EF Core 7.0`.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

In this case, `UserMaster` and `Role` classes would have no changes.

And `UsersInRoles` class would look like this:

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(UserId ), nameof(RoleId))]
[Table("UsersInRoles")]
public class UsersInRoles
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("UserMaster")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public UserMaster UserMaster { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```