# Entity Framework Code first creates unexpected Tables and Relationships

Tags: entity-framework

Using EntityFramework 6.1.3, I've got the following

```
  public class RacesContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Race> Races { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sailboat> Sailboats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VenueParticipation> VenueParticipations { get; set; }

}


public class Crew
{
    public int CrewId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Sailboat
{
    [Key]
    public int SailboatId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Skipper { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Crew> BoatCrew { get; set; }
}

public class VenueParticipation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sailboat> Boats { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Race> Races { get; set; }
}

public class Race
{
    [Key]
    public  int  RaceId { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public DateTime Occurs { get; set; }

}
```

EF creates the Creates the Crews table with the proper PK and FK as I would expect. But creates the Races Sailboats, VenueParticipations tables in an unexpected way. Sailboats get's the expected PK but the unexpected FK VenueParticipation_Id as does Races. I was expecting the VenueParticipations table to get FKs to the others allowing a many to many relationship.. I'm sure I'm missing something here. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can either configure the joining tables VenueParticipationSailboat, VenueParticipationRace with the proper FKs or you can use the fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VenueParticipation>() 
.HasMany(t => t.Sailboats) 
.WithMany(t => t.VenueParticipations) 
.Map(m => 
{ 
    m.ToTable("VenueParticipationSailboat"); 
    m.MapLeftKey("VenueParticipationID"); 
    m.MapRightKey("SailboatID"); 
});
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany

Comment: Otherwise, remove the collections from VenueParticipation and set them up as FK depending on what you are trying to achieve (public int SailboatId { get; set; }  [ForeignKey("SailboatId")] public virtual <Sailboat> Boat { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks I was trying to do it w/o resorting to the to the modelBuilder. I can see adding this.Sailboats = new HashSet<Sailboat>(); to the race ctor and vice versa to the Sailboat ctor does the trick, but I cannot seem to populate the mapping.

Comment: You can do it without modelbuilder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648600/many-to-many-mapping-using-data-annotations

Comment: Personally, I prefer the model builder. Keeps the POCOs plain and separates concerns.

Comment: You make a good point. I was just evaluating the maturity of the framework vs traditional data first methodologies.

Comment: Yeah, EF7 is dropping the EDMX https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890367.aspx