# Why is this Entity Framework code not creating a join table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have an ASP.NET identity user class that I wish to extend with a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public MyUser()
    {
        Groups = new List<Group>();
    }
}
```

Group is defined thus:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<MyUser> MyUsers { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a migration for these objects, I get a MyUser_Id field on my Groups table, which gets overwritten whenever any user adds a group to their collection.

If I uncomment the other end of the relationship in the Group class, I do get a GroupMyUsers join table, which I can seed using Group. However, when I attempt to access the MyUser.Groups property an `EntityCommandExecutionException` is thrown, stating that 'MyUserGroups' is not a valid object.

Comment: What does your FluentAPI configuration look like?  If the answer is, "I don't know", then take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx.  You likely need to configure the relationship in the OnModelCreating method.

Comment: I was hoping that the code-first conventions would take care of that side of things - am I expecting too much of it?

Comment: Yes, if you want the junction table to be 'invisible'.  FluentAPI is intended to be a part of code-first, not an exception to it.  You can create your own junction table and do it with DataAnnotations if you like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648600/many-to-many-mapping-using-data-annotations However, the way you're expecting it to work will, I believe, require one of those two solutions.